# Format of _escaped_fragment_ for complex states

Tags: web-crawlers, ajax

I understand that for a url such as `www.example.com/about`, Google's crawler will look for `www.example.com?escaped_fragment_=about`. However, what will google use as the value for the `escaped_fragment_param` for a URL such as `www.example.com/about/info`?

Comment: Do you mean `www.example.com/#!about`? There's no need for escaped fragment in the URLs you posted. And this sort of single-page application design is very user-unfriendly anyway, so you may want to reconsider it.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Biased (many major websites out today are in fact SPA) and uninformed (SPA's are crawled by Google in a special way requiring the _escaped_fragment_ param) comments do not help other people reading questions.

Comment: You should reconsider your opinion very carefully before you call the above either "biased" or "uninformed". It is based on many more years of experience than you seem to think. And the intent is to help _you_.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I can now confirm that crawler will add the full path as the value of the param. Thus www.example.com/about/info will be crawled as www.example.com?_escaped_fragment_=about/info

Note: In order for crawlers to crawl in this manner, `<meta name="fragment" content="!">` has to be added to the head of your main ajax page e.g. index.html

Comment: No, it won't. `_escaped_fragment_` stuff only comes into play when you have `#!` URIs (which are obsolete now we have `pushState` and friends)

Comment: @Quentin https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/174992# Read point 3 & 4 of the step by step guide. Besides that, I can confirm from the server logs that these requests in the format I note above are being received.

Comment: There's no sign of the use of meta tags to force Google to treat the page as if it content came from a different URL in the question.